# Android: Dynamic values in xml components?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to learn the basics of Android development and I can't find any questions regarding dynamic values inside xml components.

Say I have template which defines several components in xml using this style:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#a6c"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
        style="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/card_back_title" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then I have a value which I have generated in java:

```
    String[] myCards = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cards);
    int rnd = new Random().nextInt(myCards.length);
    Log.i("myApp", myCards[rnd]);
```

How can I reference the java value `myCards[rnd]` from inside the modified xml components?

[image]

Comment: have you already checked [android data bindings](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, Data Binding is currently the best practice solution for this requirement.

For getting started, you can check out section **One Way Data Binding** here:
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Applying-Data-Binding-for-Views

Main points are:

1. Enable data binding in gradle

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   android {
       // ..
       dataBinding.enabled = true // put as last line in this block
   }
   ```
2. Provide reference to the object you want use in xml with `<data></data>` element, where outter-most tag should be `<layout></layout>`
3. On the data-binding layout reference Java object, set the view model

   ```
   mBinding.setMyCardViewModel(myCardViewModel)
   ```
4. Access the object with `{@myCardViewModel.someValue}` notation in the xml

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple.

Just **reference the TextView** in your Activity,

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
```

Now, all you need to do is **set the text of this TextView**,

```
textView.setText(myCards[rnd]);
```

That's it!

Note, that you should use the TextView's id as "@+id/text1".

Comment: I'm not sure I'm doing it right as it says 'cannot resolve symbol text1' when I try to reference.

Comment: Are you sure you using @+id/text1 as your identifier? Just copy and paste this otherwise.